# How to get the azure AD token from url to a component in react?

Tags: reactjs, azure

I have a react app with a user flow management system with Azure AD. I'm clicking on a button to call the Azure AD url to get the access of Sign-in page. After entering the data, I'm clicking on the Signing button and I'm getting the url as follows

**localhost:3000/#id_token=XXXXXXXXXX**

And the loading page says that "This site can't provide a secure connection. Localhost sent an invalid response."

**The problem is how can I get this token to my react component to decode it by jwt-decode and do the rest?** I tried with creating a route as follows to catch the url but that component never shows. Still loading the Error page with the token url.

```
<Route path='/#id_token=' component={TokenComponent} />
```

This is my code

**Signin.js**

```
class Signin extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Link to='/azureUrl'>Go to Azure</Link>
        )
    }
}
```

**index.js**

```
render(
    <AppProvider>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/#id_token=' component={TokenComponent} />
          <Route path='/azureUrl' component={() => { 
               window.location.href='http://XXX.b2clogin.com/XXXXXXXXXXXX'
               return null
          }} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </AppProvider>
)
```